# Can i put my own functions in UserRepository if i implement from interface

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I am following this from symfony docs

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
```

Now my questions , if i want to have my own functions like `retrievePassowrd()` then can i declare that in repository or i need to create a new interface and then extend userRepo from that intertface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have your own functions in the repository.

Comment: so u mean i don't need to first create new interface and then have empty functions there and then implement userRepository from new interface. I think i read some where that if we implement interface then we cn't add functions which not in the parent interface

Comment: yes you can add functions that aren't in the implemented interface. an interface only requires that implementing classes implement all of the interface methods.